# How to transfer data between ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, uikit

I'm currently working on the currency rates app. I have a `main` ViewController which has a UILabel which presents parsed rate for selected currencies. Also, there is a button which is used for changing one of the currency rates in order to get a new rate (`second` ViewController is presented with **N** tableView cells). 
I have some troubles with transferring data of new selected value to the `main` ViewController. When I select a new rate, I get this error for UILabel:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

I guess I know how to fix it - create a variable inside `main` and set its value inside `second` viewcontroller, but i don't know how do it properly. Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
class MainVC: UITableViewController {

    var convertedValue: String = ""

    // some stuff

    func parseCurrency(top: String) {
        let URL_Exchange = URL(string: "MY URL\(top)")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL_Exchange) {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "result")
            queue.async {
                let JSON = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                let jsonData = JSON!.data(using: .utf8)!
                let result: Rates = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Rates.self, from: jsonData)
            
                let currencies = result.conversion_rates?.dictionary
                var doubleVar:Double = 0
                for item in currencies! {
                    if (item.key == self.BottomCurrency.sublabel) {
                        doubleVar = item.value as! Double
                    }
                }
            
                // this value is the text to print inside "Result" Label
                let mult = Double(round(10000*doubleVar * self.InputText)/10000)
             

                self.convertedValue = String(mult)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if self.convertedValue == "0" {
                        self.Result.text = String(0)
                    } else {
                        // Here I get an error
                        self.Result.text = self.formatNumber(num: Double(self.convertedValue))
                    }
                }
            }
    
        }
        task.resume()
}
```

Code for `second` VC:

```
class SecondVC: UITableViewController {
    private var temp: Int = 0

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        if isBeingDismissed {
            // updating temp value...
            let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "main") as! MainVC
            vc.parseCurrency(top: Currencies[temp].short)
            // or to call vc.convertedValue = something
            // vc.parseCurrency(...)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing data between view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: This question is the same as the other： https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, the reason that your code is crashing is that the property `Result` you are calling on a freshly created instance of `main` view controller, is actually an `IBOutlet` pointing to a `UILabel!` which is not yet created.

#### Important!

There is a great amount of resources available on the internet on passing data between view controllers so I am pointing you towards already existing post with huge amount of answers: [Passing data between view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However, I will describe one of the available ways to solve it below

#### Delegation

One way to solve it would be to use a "traditional" UIKit pattern which is `Delegation`.

You simply create a protocol, that will enable a way for the `secondVC` communicate with `mainVC`

```swift
protocol SecondVCDelegate: AnyObject {
    func secondVCDidSelect(currency: String)
}
```

Then you add a `weak` property on the `secondVC`

```swift
class SecondVC: UITableViewController {

    weak var delegate: SecondVCDelegate?

    // ...

}
```

And now you should be able to pass any value you want to the delegate. For the sake of the example, you could do it on the `didSet` observer of the `temp` property

```swift
class SecondVC: UITableViewController {

    private var temp: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            delegate?.secondVCDidSelect(currency: Currencies[temp].short)
        }
    }

    weak var delegate: SecondVCDelegate?

}
```

> Personally I would call the delegate the moment user is selecting the value, and not store it in the `temp` property

the only thing missing is setting a `mainVC` as the delegate of the `secondVC` and conforming to the protocol. Perfect place to do it is at the moment you are presenting the `secondVC` from `mainVC`

```swift
let viewController: SecondVC = // init SecondVC or load from storyboard
viewController.delegate = self
// present secondVC
```

```swift
extension MainVC: SecondVCDelegate {
    func secondVCDidSelect(currency: String) {
        parseCurrency(top: currency)
    }
}
```

I encourage you to read more about Delegation since this is a very popular pattern in the iOS development

[Delegation in Swift](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/delegation-in-swift/) by John Sundell

Comment: answer is brilliant! Well, it worked for me for a half. Text inside UILabel updated but I still get the same error. Your thought about not created label inside instance makes the sense. Do you know any methods or ways to handle this issue? I will be grateful!

Comment: why do you even call `instantiateViewController` to init a mainVC, is it deallocated? I thought you are presenting secondVC on top of the mainVC so there would be no reason to create a new mainVC

Comment: as a rule of thumb when working with storyboards, you should avoid doing any view setup before `viewDidLoad` is called. So move any label setup to the `viewDidLoad`. Also there is a property on a `UIViewController` to check if view is loaded, its called `isViewLoaded`

Comment: ```isViewLoaded``` solved the issue. Thanks a lot!!! You were right about presenting secondVC on top of the main - I do exactly what you've described. Honestly, I have a huge lack of knowledge about swift development 'cause I'm a first year student and didn't get much time to practice and read documentation. Hope to fix it during summer :)

Comment: You are welcome and good luck! Make sure to take advantage of all the available content from people like John Sundell or Paul Hudson. Their website are goldmines of amazing content!